# use androidx.fragment.app.Fragment，I found that I can't initialize initAdapter() in initView(),Why?

Tags: android, kotlin

Code using kotlin,
first,this is my error code.

this is my used extends BaseFragment

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val cacheView = mView == null
        if (cacheView) {
            mView = inflater.inflate(getFragLayoutResID(), container, false)
            initView(mView!!)
        }
        return mView
    }

    //When used in an activity
    fun addFragment(context: FragmentActivity, fragmentContainer: Int) {
        val fragmentManager = context.supportFragmentManager
        val ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        ft.replace(fragmentContainer, this, javaClass.simpleName).addToBackStack(javaClass.simpleName)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss()
        ft.setMaxLifecycle(this, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
    }
```

this is my HomeActivity

```
homeVideoFragment.addFragment(mContext as FragmentActivity, mainFrameLayout.id)
```

this is my HomeFragment

```
    //HomeFragment
    override fun initView(view: View) {//this is my homeFragment
        initAdapter()
        //init()
    }

    private var homeVideoAdapter: HomeVideoAdapter? = null
    private fun initAdapter() {//this is my init adapter
        val homeVideoManager = LinearLayoutManager(mContext, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        homeVideoAdapter = HomeVideoAdapter(mContext!!)
        home_video_rv.layoutManager = homeVideoManager
        home_video_rv.adapter = homeVideoAdapter
    }

    private fun init() = runBlocking {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            initAdapter()
            //GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            //presenter!!.getVideoClassPost(AllPort.POST_GET_VIDEO_HOME)//network requests
            //}.await()
        }
    }
```

When the code is run like this, it will report an error: home_video_rv must not be null.

But when I use init(), it works fine.

Although successful, but can not make network requests.

Why is this problem occurring?

Comment: call initView method in OnViewCreated of your fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use onViewCreated method**

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val cacheView = mView == null
            if (cacheView) {
                mView = inflater.inflate(getFragLayoutResID(), container, false)
            }
            return mView
        }

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initView(view)
    }
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer, your answer solved my problem, thank you.:)